# glibc differences between CentOS versions

Tags: c, linux, centos, glibc, libc

CentOS seems to bundle a new version of glibc library RPM with every release.

- 6.0 has glibc-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64.rpm
- 6.1 has glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.x86_64.rpm
- 6.2 has glibc-2.12-1.47.el6.x86_64.rpm
- 6.3 has glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64

What is the different between the glibc versions in each of these RPMs? I am specifically looking for the implementation of mallopt() function that allows us to configure the number of arenas used by malloc().

mallopt(M_ARENA_MAX, 1) has no effect in 6.0, 6.1 and 6.2, but it works in 6.3, even though
all of the versions of CentOS seem to have the same version of GLibc - 2.12.

My specific question is: even though glibc on all CentOS 6.X releases report the same version number - 2.12 - mallopt(M_ARENA_MAX) only works on CentOS 6.3. Is there anyway to find out the difference in glibc versions bundled with the CentOS version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference are release or security patches.

```
rpm -q --changelog glibc-2.12-1.80.el6
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be described in the changelog of the glibc package. I haven't used CentOS for a while so I cant point you to the correct location.

Comment: The surprising thing is that GLibc version is unchanged across all the CentOS versions. So, I think this cannot be a change done by the folks at GNU/glibc. It must be CentOS or RedHat upstream.

Comment: Yes, all the packages you mention are patched versions of the same upstream version (2.12). The second set of versions (1.7, 1.25, etc.) is the version of CentOS/RedHat patches. The patches might originate from later versions of glibc, but have been backported by RedHat. Happens with lots of packages.

Comment: Martin, thanks for the replies. So, the major/minor revision of glibc stays constant even though many patches are being applied to the library? It seems that the check for glibc version is insufficient - the library could change without a change in the version number..

Comment: Correct, you really need to look at the full version number.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'full version number'. Glibc only offers 'gnu_get_libc_version()', which only returns 2.12. I don't have access to any further details of the specific version running on CentOS. Do you know any other way to obtain it?

Comment: I meant the full version of the package. I don't know if you can get the extra version info in code.